# do not receive the POSTed data in php code ( cakephp)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cakephp

I am trying to use ajax for retrieving data from my server. I use cakephp and jquery.
The ajax code is as follows:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".viewMode").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:"viewModeSwitching",
            data: {
                mobileViewCookie:12,
                },
            success:function(result){
//          window.location.href = result;
             }
        }
);

  });


});
</script>
...
<?php
    echo "<br>";
    echo $this->Form->button(__('Desktop View'), array('type' => 'button','class'       =>"viewMode",));
    echo "<br>";    
?>
```

This works well, in firebug I see that the POST is sent with value mobileViewCookie=12.
The point is that my cakephp controllerfunction 'viewModeSwitching' cannot retrieve that data.
I checked $this->data, $this->params, $_POST, etc but no sign of the data that had been send in the POST message.
Any suggestions?

/Antoine

Comment: what version of CakePHP are you using?

Comment: if the problem is within the controller, you need to show us that controller. Also, cake version please (and tag accordingly)

Comment: Look at the network tab in your browsers inspector or use a tool like Charles to figure out if the request is send at all and what happens inside the request if it is send.

Comment: where is your controller code. I think you facing problem there.